How to best fix a crack in concrete balcony corner?
So I was recently pondering a problem with a crack in a corner of a balcony made of concrete as shown below in the picture. I am not a builder (rather an amateur handyman) but would like to educate myself of how this might be best approached if a solution would ever be required.
The previous owners indicated they had purchased the home back in 2006 and this crack was already there. How might this have happened and for what reasons one could speculate ? I am not an expert but from the photo I cannot ascertain if an attempt was ever made at a repair, and the owners seemd to not have been bothered by it during their stay ...


The crack gets larger in size from the bottom to the top of the ledge that is about 60cm high, and the widest crack gap is about 9-12mm. It is static, ie not getting larger day by day (contrary to what some might have thought). The crack appears uniform and identical in size from both sides of the balcony. The balcony itsel is rather small and a huge load in that corner would probably not have been the cause of the break ...
I was told that one of the best ways to fix this permanently, would be by employing somekind of stainless steel anchors with epoxy to effectively "stitch" the crack together, and then to finish it with an appropriate concrete filler etc.
What are the experiences and thoughts on the best way to do this fix and how much should one expect to pay for professionals to do such work ? What commercial systems are best suited for this permanent mend ? The house is situated in a European country...
thanks in advance for your suggestions...
cheers, MM

I do not think that is a DIY repair.  Same crack at both sides and seems to be getting bigger/wider, sounds like something is giving away/collapsing/sinking, even if slowly.  You want a professional there to see what is happening.  Does it have posts/columns holding up the end, or is it free standing(only anchored to the building)?

Difference in level of excitement applicable if the crack is actually increasing, (actively moving) or merely the geometry of the crack from the balcony means it's wider at the top than the bottom, which is what I read from that description and see in the photos.

Well if this might be happening at 1mm / 20 years it may not be an immediate problem ... It is a free-standing concrete slab balcony about 60cm wide, going along the long side of the house. The entire double-storey house is on large and thick river-rock foundation with thick concrete slab walls everywhere, and on a slight hill.

@Ecnerwal - no it is not moving. As I mentioned it appears to have been there at the same gap/distance over many years already. It might have happened due to some poor workmanship/finish in that part of the house.

If you use a piece of string or a sheet of paper, can you run it all the way from top to botyom?  That is, is thete any reinforcing connection in the gap?

@Rohit Gupta - I have not tested if there is steel reinforcement inside yet, but will do at at the earliest convenience... My initial impressions are that there is no reinforcement and it was not ment to be. Perhaps it would have helped to do so.

The taper of the gap (which you've described as "increasing in size from the bottom to the top") is not concerning if it's staying put there, as it settled to 20 years ago or whatever at the time of construction.
Presumably it was poured in place and the balcony deflected a bit under its own weight when the formwork was removed. If it's solidly attached to the floor of the balcony so it's not in danger of falling off, I would not worry about it.
If the gap is increasing over time, you should be concerned, and you should consult a licensed structural engineer about it.
I would not describe that as a crack - it clearly was never attached to the wall - it was merely poured adjacent to it. So rather than something solid cracking into two pieces, you have two separate pieces which started out touching (evidently) and moved slightly to form a gap between them. Nothing actually cracked, and there's no evidence that any attempt was made to make the joint structural at time of construction.

The house was built in 1986. It is not an actively moving crack but it doesn't look good (as most cracks in walls don't).

You could inject grout to fill it. I don't see a practical need to attempt to find a way to apply stainless steel anchors to it (drill all the way from the corner to the wall - more than 60 cm? Have fun with that) as it's not actually going anywhere.

I was thinking more along the lines of using Helibars (Helifix) type reinforcement that require a machined cut in the sides of the balcony ledges, inserted and then epoxied over and finished to blend in. But just some fast setting and very liquidy cement might also do fine to fill-in the gap.

I think that @Ecnerwall is trying to tell you that this is an aesthetic problem. If it hasn't moved in decades and hasn't caused any other problems then fill it and stucco over it, or caulk it and paint it, and quit over-thinking it.
